# Flutter Copy all tables and data from old database into new database when creating new one

Tags: flutter, sqflite

At the old version of my flutter application i put my sqflite database in custom folder.Now i want to create other in default folder.

The problem is here!

I want to do copy all tables with it's data from old database in new database. I it is possible to copy all tables and data from old database into new database when creating new database?

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same need when migrating to sqlcipher from sqflite and this is how I made it work:

```
  final String dbPath = join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'new.db');


  return openDatabase(
    dbPath,
    version: 1,
    password: 'YourPassword If using sqlcipher',
    onCreate: (db, version) async {
      AppLogger.insertLog("DB # onCreate");
      //Your default onCreate logic
      // then add
      await migrateOldDatabaseData(db);
    },
    onUpgrade: (db, oldVersion, newVersion) async {
    // Your default onUpgrade logic
    },
  );
```

The migrateOldDatabaseData function is:

```
Future<void> migrateOldDatabaseData(Database newDb) async {
  String oldDBPath = join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'old.db');
  await File(oldDBPath).exists();
  bool exists = File(oldDBPath).existsSync();
  if (exists) {
    Database oldDB = await openDatabase(oldDBPath, version: 'your old db version as int');
    var tableNames = (await oldDB.query('sqlite_master', where: 'type = ?', whereArgs: ['table']))
                     .map((row) => row['name'] as String)
                     .toList(growable: false);
    for (int i = 0; i < tableNames.length; i++) {
      final List<Map<String, dynamic>> result = await oldDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM ${tableNames[i]}");
      for (int j = 0; j < result.length; j++) {
        await newDb.insert(tableNames[i], result[j]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will check if old database file exists, if it does, it will read the database table names, query the table and insert its data into the new database.